# How to plot a line using its polynomial coefficients?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a data and 2 classes. After separating them I want to plot a line between them with final weight vector. Is there a suitable method for my final weight which is `3 by 1` matrix. For example the `[1,3,-4]` matrix is equivalent to `x1+3x2-4=0` equation. How can I draw this equation's line in plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`fplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html) to plot a function:

```
w = [1,3,-4];
% create a function handle for w1*x1+w2*x2+w3 => x2 = -(w1x1+w3)/w2
x2 = @(x1) -(w(1)*x1+w(3))/w(2); 
fplot(x2, [0, 10]);
title('w_1x_1+w_2x_2+w_3 = 0')
xlabel('x_1')
ylabel('x_2')
```

[image]